# MongoDB - updating single document with "one-to-many-relationships"

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, relationship

I need to create a "summary-document" with queries based on all the documents stored in another collection. The documents I need to perform queries on have a structure like this:

```
RatioCollection

{
  keyName: String,
  data: {
    ratio1: Number,
    ratio2: Number
    ...
  }
}
```

Every unique `keyName` has a data-object with the same ratios stored in it. Now I need to create a summary collection like this:

```
RatioSummaryCollection

{
  ratio1: {
    max: Number,
    min: Number
  },
  ratio2: {
    max: Number,
    min: Number
  }
  ...
}
```

which will ultimately just contain one document created from all of my ratio-documents, which auto-updates when the different ratios change.

How can this be acheived, or is it even possible?

Comment: Automatic updating won't work. MongoDB isn't built for things like that. If you want automatic updating, you will have to implement it on the application layer. You could use a MapReduce job to generate and re-generate the ratio summary collection, but it won't auto-update. So that solution would only be sufficient when the summaries don't need to be updated in real-time. When you need real-time updates, have your application update the `RatioSummaryCollection` when it updates a document in the `RatioCollection`.

Comment: @Philipp this comment is worth being an answer

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I will write a complete answer when frank21 tells us which of the two variants he wants. A proper answer would require code, and I am not going to write code for both variants when it isn't needed.

Comment: You could try Two Phase Commits: :http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/#perform-two-phase-commits

Comment: @Philipp The solution you suggest without auto-update fits best, I have no need for real-time updates, I just thought that was the most intuitive way to go.